# Php - variable in variable name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with several checkboxes. These boxes have one row each in a mysql db if checked.
Now, I need to have a loop that build a query to delete all rows that is not checked.
I tried the one below but the array is never populated...
Any help is appreciated...

```php
$chk_cab_1  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_1']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_2  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_2']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_3  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_3']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_4  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_4']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_5  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_5']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_6  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_6']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_7  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_7']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_8  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_8']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_9  = isset($_POST['chk_cab_9']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_10 = isset($_POST['chk_cab_10']) ?: 0;
$chk_cab_11 = isset($_POST['chk_cab_11']) ?: 0;


$check_cab    = array();
$del_cab_ids  = array();
for($i = 1; $i<=$counter; $i++) {
    $check_cab["chk_cab_$i"]     = $chk_cab_$i;
    if($check_cab["chk_cab_$i"] == 0) {
       $del_cab_ids[] = $i;
    }
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable 
        WHERE first_id = $t_key
        AND second_id IN ($del_cab_ids)";
```

Comment: You can use `<input name="chk_cab[5]" type="checkbox" value="1" />` so that you get an array immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the HTML, if possible to rename the checkboxes like this:

```
<input name="chk_cab[0]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
...
<input name="chk_cab[5]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
...
```

And then invert the query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE first_id = ?";

if (isset($_POST['chk_cab']) {
    $ids = join(',', array_map('intval', array_keys($_POST['chk_cab'])));

    $sql .= " AND second_id NOT IN ($ids)";
}
```

**Important**: This assumes that all entries matched by `first_id = <whatever>` are accounted for within `[1 .. $counter]`.

Comment: Wrt "inverting the query"; it's *not* strictly semantically equivalent and could delete data erroneously here -- A case might be made that this would be a better solution overall, but I would rather keep the approach the *same* as in the original to avoid issues (e.g. "phantom deletes") with concurrency.

Comment: @user2864740 While that is technically possible; the query is limited by the first part of the query; in any case, I've updated the answer to make OP stop and think first.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array *at the start*. This avoids nonsense with ["variable variables"](http://php.net/variables.variable)<sup>1</sup>

```
$del_cab_ids = array();
for($i = 1; $i<=$counter; $i++) {
   # it's easier/cleaner to use a dynamic key than a dynamic variable
   $v = isset($_POST['chk_cab_' . $i]) ?: 0;
   if ($v == 0) {
     $del_cab_ids[] = $i;
   }
}
```

Also, *at least* use mysqli_real_escape_string .. but I recommend using placeholders and binding the values ..

---

<sup>1</sup> While I don't agree with "variable variables", the usage is as such:

```
$varname = "chk_cab_" . $i;
$value = $$varname;

# or
$value = ${"chk_cab_" . $i}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
$check_cab["chk_cab_$i"] = ${'chk_cab_'.$i}
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete structure seems to be a bit ... ugly. Sorry for that. ;)
So you can avoid that mass of unnecessary variables by using a simple array for your post data.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="my-checkbox[]" id="my-checkbox-1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="my-checkbox[]" id="my-checkbox-2" /> 2
```

With this you can grab all the IDs in one simple line of PHP code as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['my-checkbox'])) $myIDs = array_map('intval', $_POST['my-checkbox']);
```

So all your post IDs have been validated as an integer value so you can proceed with your database statement. For this I recommend using statements like the PDO object gives you with PDO Statements to avoid security issues. Have a look at the following example:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE first_id = :first_id AND FIND_IN_SET(CAST(second_id AS char), :second_id)";

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':first_id' => $first_id,
        ':second_id' => implode(",", $myIDs)
    ));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // error handling
}
```

That 's all. With this small example all your structure and security problems should have been solved.

Comment: I 'm always open for advice. Where 's the sql injection problem in your eyes?

Comment: Whoops, that was wrong (binding prevents the SQL injection) .. but does this even *work*? I would expect passing in a CSV *string* as as placeholder value would not.

Comment: Yes, this even works. You 've validated the post data before with intval() and after that pdo does even an extra escaping with in the statement. This works fine. ;)

Comment: I mean, *why/how* is does this placeholder (:second) result in `.. IN ('1','2','3')` and not `.. IN ('1,2,3')`?

Comment: Just tested it on my localhost, cos I was not quite sure. But it works perfectly. The placeholder is not replaced as a string. Just fine, comma seperated integer values. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$del_cab_ids = implode(',', $del_cab_ids);
$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable 
    WHERE first_id = $t_key
    AND second_id IN ($del_cab_ids)";
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even mention the horrible SQL injection vulnerability this solution has.

Comment: Second Ricudo, I was pointing why his query was having problems executing.

Comment: When i give examples for SQLs, i neither write it perfectly save. The examples are only for giving a hint into the right direction, not just copy and paste.

Comment: I am aware of the SQL injection issue. I wrote the sql to show in a simple way how I will use the array.